# Reversing all the bytes or blocks of a partition to easily resize the partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, kernel, mount

My current problem is that I want a way to dual boot a Linux system with a Windows or macOS system and still be able to resize both systems, but without moving them. For example, if I had a Windows system on my first partition and a Linux system on my second partition, if I wanted to add space to my Linux partition I would have to shrink the Windows partition, move the Linux partition, then grow the Linux partition. I would rather not use LVM because this is not compatible with Windows or macOS.

To solve this problem, I had a (somewhat crazy) idea to reverse all the bytes or blocks (depending on the actual implementation) in a partition so that the data grows from the *end* of the partition. I could write a kernel module to implement this for the Linux system and then if I wanted to grow my Linux system, I could just shrink my Windows partition and grow my Linux partition.

1. Is there a better way to do this? I feel like this approach is a bit... questionable.
2. What is the best way of implementing this in the kernel? I would like to have block devices (so I would be reversing the blocks) that I could just point the mount command to or point the mkfs command to, the same way you would use /dev/sda1. I would rather not just modify the code of, say, ext4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible because other processes with low level I/O access (like the kernel itself) will probably just ignore your kernel module and cause havoc. Other than that it may cause some serious performance issues since every program that opens an I/O disk-stream would need to go through your module. It sure sounds cool but i don't think it's worth pursuing without help from experienced kernel developers.

Comment: I'm writing a kernel module now to test it, but you're probably right. If it doesn't work too well, at least I will have learned how to write a kernel module!